# Remote live update process (like Sonarr) /plugin system ASP.NET 5

Tags: c#, plugins, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, live-update

I'm trying to implement a 'modular' framework in ASP.NET 5 (currently dnx46 on RC1, but soon I'll migrate the code to netcore10 on 1.0.0 RTM)

With this, I mean I'll be creating a module for each mini application that can use the framework's services, ...

However, I'm stuck on how to implement a plugin system that can plugin code while the application is running (like Wordpress for example), which should be possible now since c# doesn't need to be precompiled anymore.
If this is possible by plugging in a dll, this is also fine for me.

A second part (which I think needs the same solution) is to send updates a remote server (for example an apache server) without web deploy on my application without needing to restart it myself. For this, I was looking at the code of an application I'm using on my NAS called Sonarr (a series manager and downloader formerly known as NzbDrone).

[Sonarr Update Engine](https://github.com/Sonarr/Sonarr/tree/develop/src/NzbDrone.Update/UpdateEngine)

However, I don't understand what they actually do to make it work. It seems like they set up a second (update)application that does the update on their main application, copies the new files to the application, 'installs?' it and restarts it.

Is someone  able to explain how they do it, or even better, how I could do the live update myself?

Answer (score 0):

For the plugin part, I may have found a solution using JSON files to inject my dependencies in my application. https://radu-matei.github.io/blog/aspnet-core-json-dependency-injection/